# Rotate object by 360 degrees with different Images in Android?

Tags: java, android, rotation, image-rotation

I am creating an Android App to rotate an image of Car by 360 degrees.
I want to rotate the object with different image files of same object (eg Car)

Here is the [**Example**](http://www.cardekho.com/hyundai-eon-360-view.htm) that I want to implement in my app.

**Is it possible to use different images in rotating the Object in Android?**

**Is there any API or Class available for this?**

Here is my android code -

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.graphics.Matrix;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnTouchListener;
import android.widget.ImageView;
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnTouchListener {

private ImageView dialer;
private float y=0;
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
    double r=Math.atan2(event.getX()-dialer.getWidth()/2, dialer.getHeight()/2-event.getY());
    int rotation=(int)Math.toDegrees(r);
    switch (event.getAction()) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
            //x=event.getX();
            y=event.getY();
            updateRotation(rotation);
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            break;
    }//switch       

    return true;

}//onTouch
private void updateRotation(double rot){
    float newRot=new Float(rot);
    Bitmap bitmap=BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.drawable.round_button_big);
    Matrix matrix=new Matrix();
    matrix.postRotate(newRot,bitmap.getWidth()/2,bitmap.getHeight()/2);
    if(y>250){
        Bitmap reDrawnBitmap=Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap,0,0,bitmap.getWidth(),bitmap.getHeight(),matrix,true);
        dialer.setImageBitmap(reDrawnBitmap);
    }
    else{
        Bitmap reDrawnBitmap=Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap,0,0,bitmap.getWidth(),bitmap.getHeight(),matrix,true);
        dialer.setImageBitmap(reDrawnBitmap);
    }
}
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    dialer = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
    dialer.setOnTouchListener(this);
    }//onCreate

}
```

Comment: try openGL example. But you would need a 3d model of the car.

Comment: ok Lalith B, I'll try this

Comment: I used MIN3D framework in android for 3d application, here is link -  http://www.mat-d.com/site/tutorial-load-a-3d-obj-model-with-min3d-for-android/.  Hope it will help you.

Comment: Hi @Deepu Hiw you implemented this functionality? Could you please explain ?

Answer (score 2):

If you have X amount of pictures from different angles of the car, you only have to listen to the onTouch when you want to change the ImageView.

I advice to use an [LevelListDrawable](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/LevelListDrawable.html) and use [setImageLevel](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.html#setImageLevel%28int%29) to smoothly walk through them.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.
I came to know about Panorama, is it usable in this case?

Comment: @lon Aalbers Could you please explain how we can use LevelListDrawable and setImageLevel for tha same scenario  ?